# Is it possible to pass two arguments in c?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I have written a C program where I declared a function `reverse(int i)`. When I compile and run the program, it runs fine despite passing two arguments like this `reverse((i++, i))`. Why doesn't this cause a syntax error? `reverse` expects one argument.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    void reverse(int i);
    int main()
    { 
            reverse(1); 

    }
    void reverse(int i)
    {
            if (i > 5)
                    return ;
            printf("%d ", i); 
            return reverse((i++, i));
    }
```

Comment: `(i++, i)`is **one** parameter.

Comment: Passing `n` arguments to a function that accepts `k != n` arguments is not a syntax error, it's more of a type error (that is, semantics error).

Comment: If an answer solved your question, you can mark it as an answer by pressing the gray tick to the left of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(i++, i)` seems to execute `i++`, then evaluate to `i`, the last operand to `,`. You can see that here:

```
// Notice the ( , )
int i = (puts("Inside\n"), 2); // Prints "Inside"

printf("%d\n", i); // Prints 2
```

It didn't cause an error because you only passed one argument. That one argument though was a sequence of effects that evaluated to `i`.

Answer (score 8):

You're not passing two arguments - that would be `reverse(i++, i)` (which incidentally would invoke undefined behaviour because of the lack of a sequence point between (`i++` and `i`).

You're passing `(i++, i)` as a single argument. Since it is inside an additional pair of parentheses, the comma here does not separate the arguments of the function, but rather acts as the comma operator.

Comment: I got it now . Thanks for your reply